# How to apply this html script in to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that attribute `data-toggle` and `data-target`. This is the full button script:

```
<button style="width:50%; float:left" type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btn_report" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Detail</button>
```

This button opens a simple modal. The modal can also be closed by clicking outside the modal box. However, I'd like to have some rules in the button using jQuery.

```
$('#btn_report').on('click',function(e){
    var dataSend    = "some_data";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some_function",
        cache: false,
        dataType : "json",
        data: dataSend,
        success: function(response) {
           if(response){
               $('#myModal').show();
           }else{ 
               alert("There are no data to be displayed"); return false; 
           }
        }
   })
});
```

With `data-toggle` and `data-target`, the modal is always be opened whenever I click the button. If I remove `data-toggle` and `data-target` and add `$('#myModal').show();`, the modal is not show up.

What I'd like to do is to open the modal, if there are data returned from ajax. If there aren't, the alert is fired.

The modal is simple like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content" id="printMe">
        <div class="modal-body"> Congrats, you have your data </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#myModal').modal('show');  change the code ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using a Bootstrap modal you need to use `modal('open')`, not `show()`. Try this:

```
if (response) {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
} else { 
  alert("There are no data to be displayed"); 
}
```

Also note that the `return` is redundant as you can't return anything from within the asynchronous `success` handler function.

Comment: Thank you. 
I have change it to `open` and remove the ` data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` from the button. But the modal is not show up. why?

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to diagnose that as this should work. Check the console for errors

Comment: it's working now. But, without slide effect. How to add it?

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

Add event.stopPropagation() in the click listener

```
$('#btn_report').on('click',function(e){
    event.stopPropagation();
    setTimeout(function() {
        // ajax mock
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.